# CSS scale transform on svg icon doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I tried to scale SVG icon with CSS but it doesn't work.
I used svg with symbol so my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="bloc">
  <svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#sym01"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="sym01" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M14.211 7.367c0.91-0.063 1.506-0.471 1.758-1.035 -0.346 0.22-1.35 0.439-1.914 0.22 0-0.125-0.031-0.251-0.063-0.376 -0.439-1.569-1.883-2.824-3.42-2.667 0.125-0.031 0.252-0.094 0.377-0.125 0.156-0.063 1.16-0.22 1.004-0.565 -0.127-0.314-1.35 0.219-1.568 0.282 0.313-0.094 0.783-0.282 0.846-0.627 -0.469 0.063-0.91 0.282-1.254 0.596 0.125-0.156 0.219-0.313 0.25-0.501C9.004 3.351 8.282 4.92 7.717 6.457c-0.47-0.439-0.878-0.784-1.223-0.973C5.458 4.951 4.267 4.386 2.353 3.665 2.321 4.292 2.667 5.14 3.733 5.704 3.514 5.673 3.074 5.735 2.761 5.798c0.125 0.721 0.564 1.318 1.788 1.6C3.984 7.43 3.702 7.555 3.451 7.837c0.251 0.502 0.878 1.098 1.977 0.973 -1.224 0.533-0.502 1.506 0.502 1.38 -1.726 1.757-4.424 1.632-5.961 0.157 4.047 5.49 12.833 3.263 14.149-2.071 0.973 0.031 1.568-0.345 1.914-0.722C15.467 7.649 14.652 7.555 14.211 7.367z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

and my CSS

```
.bloc svg {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    transform-origin: 8px 8px;
    transform: scale(4);
}
```

In Firefox scale is different than Chrome or IE11.

https://jsfiddle.net/korigan/0dz5hn07/

Comment: you want .bloc > svg rather than .bloc svg don't you?

Comment: Oh thanks Robert but why? Firefox interprets symbol like a svg tag?

Comment: I've explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
.bloc > svg
```

Otherwise the transform will apply to both the use and the svg elements.

According to the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

> The referenced ‘symbol’ and its contents are deep-cloned into the generated tree, with the exception that the ‘symbol’ is replaced by an ‘svg’.

And that's precisely what Firefox does.